# how to add Paypal discount_amount on cart

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

**how to add Paypal discount_amount on cart**

Every think is ok. but i can't add discount amount on paypal cart.

My code

```
$counter =0;
    $items=[];
    foreach(Input::all() as $input )
    {
        if(Input::has('item_name'.$counter))
        {
            $item=new Item();
            $item->setName(Input::get('item_name'.$counter))
                ->setCurrency('GBP')
                ->setQuantity(Input::get('item_qty'.$counter))
                ->setPrice(Input::get('item_price'.$counter));
            $items[]=$item;
        }
        $counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Before enabling the actual amount, calculate the discount of the actual price, then add the answer to the cart

Comment: i tried `$item = new Item();
$item->setName('Voucher Discount')
    ->setDescription('Voucher Discount')
    ->setCurrency('GBP')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice('-10');`